# how to hide table header for null object when uisearchbar type

Tags: xcode, uitableview

how to hide table header for null object when uisearchbar type? Here is my coding. Currently, header height does not hide when type something in UISearchbar even put [_tableview reloadData] in this function.

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
    self.currentResponder = searchBar;
    NSMutableArray *tempClientArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *tempCoyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    ....
    ....

    [_clientListGroupTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: can you explain in detail?

Comment: currently, I have store all of customer information with company information into realm DB as page load. When I type "company name" in UISearchbar, I want to hide UITableViewHeader for un-matched customer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a BOOL to detect if you are searching or not and reload table

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

if (isFromSearchResults) { 
    return 0; //set height 0, if it is from search results or whatever your condition
}
else{

    return 30; // set height for Header
}}
```

it may help you